# Trusting self signed certificates from a REST API server in apple iOS mobile apps for testing

Tags: ios, mobile, pki

I have an iOS mobile app, that connects to a REST API server that I run on a machine in the local network. Problem is that the mobile app does not trust the x509 certificate presented by the server in the TLS handshake as it is self signed.

I am new to mobile apps and want to know how to test my app with this server, that is presenting self signed certificate. It seems apple does not allow a client to trust a self signed certificate for obvious security concerns.

This should be a common problem for mobile app developers for iOS, how do you suggest fixing it ONLY for test environment. (For production, the server will have a cert signed by trusted CAs)

Are there any workarounds for developers that allow them to test with a service presenting self signed certs?

I explored some resources on YouTube that explain how to get a developer certificate for iOS apps, but it appears it is only for signing apps. I also searched in stack overflow but some of the answers are pretty old and also suggest that this capability to trust self signed cert may be removed.

Comment: The simplest way is just to trust the certificate on your device. Browse to the web site using safari on your device and then you will be able to establish a certificate trust. You can also modify the ATS settings for your app in info.plist so that it works with untrusted certificates during development.